# jQuery event bug ?

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` that contains an `<img />`.

Using *jQuery 1.7*, i bound a `mouseout` event to that `<div>`.

When the *event* is triggered, `e.target.nodeName` returns `IMG` instead of the actual `DIV` it was bound to. However if I gave the `<div>` a specific *height* and *width*, then `e.target.nodeName` returns `DIV`.

**Is this a bug?** Or is it just impossible to bind mouse events to a `<div>` with no set dimensions?

Comment: Code snippet would help. May be you are doing some silly mistake.

Comment: You first say you bind to an `a` element, then you say `div`, which is it? And yeah, code is always welcome. If something has no dimensions, how would you put your mouse over it?

Comment: show your code in jsfiddle? that way we can see what really is going on.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug. You are experiencing a browser behavior known as event bubbling. Since your `div` element has no dimensions, the mouseout event is dispatched only for the actual bounding box that is being left, in this case for the `img` element. That event is then "bubbled up" after any listeners for the original target are invoked. It proceeds to all ancestor elements of that DOM object--first to the `img` parent (your `div` where the listener is actually attached and invoked), then to the `div`'s parent element where any other listeners on that event would also run, and so on until it eventually reaches the document level or event propagation is cancelled. The event target, therefore, will be the original element that dispatched the event.

There's probably a way to structure your code differently so that you can still test for whatever it is you want to know. For instance:

```
if (e.target.nodeName == "DIV")
```

could become...

```
if ($(e.target).parent().is("div"))
```

if you are always expecting a behavior where the `img` is the only element that has a bounding box with a substantive dimension and it is a known child of the `div` element you are looking for.

If you provide the piece of code that is not functioning as intended, we may be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: What is odd, is that the event seems to be bubbling _down_. If the event was passed to the parent, I would have understood. Eventually I will replace the images with <p>, <ul>, other <div>s and who knows what. When this happens, how will jQuery decide what element to attach the event to?

I never get the simple ones :-(

Comment: Your original post said your `img` element was inside of the `div` whose mouseout event you were listening for. That makes the `div` the parent element. Events do not, by definition, propagate downward. Seeing your related HTML markup and your jQuery listener attachment might help us decide how to instruct you further in resolving what you're attempting to do.

Comment: My second line stated that I bound the event to the <div> I will try to supply some code when I get off work.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a bug. This happens because of event bubbling. The event that happens when you mouse over that `img`  bubbles up to the parent/outer container `div` where you hook your listener. In the end, it will bubble up again to the `document`.

No.1 question is, what are you trying to achieve here? This behavior is completely normal and isn't a bug. People expect the event to bubble up to the container for performance reason, that is why people use `.bind()` instead of just assigning a single `.mouseout()` directly to the img element as this is inefficient since then the browser will have to scan the entire DOM for that particular img element.

Since you're in 1.7, anyway you should use `.on()` :

```
$(elements).on(events [, selector] [, data], handler);
```

So in your case, it would be

```
$('#div_id').on('mouseout', 'img', function(e){
//dostuff
});
```

This way, the event only propagates from your img to an element where you define `#div_id` which is your div, instead of waiting for it to bubble up to `document` root.